# Why there might a memory leak occus when using Handler

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-handler

There is a warning if we use non-static Handler: 'handler should be static, else it is prone to memory leaks.'

I have read below links and I know what their mean.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7909437/619424
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11336822/619424

But after read the source of [Handler.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Handler.java/), [Message.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Message.java/) and [Looper.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Looper.java/), I'm confused...

In [Looper.loop()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Looper.java#Looper.loop%28%29) method, we can see below statements:

```
msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);

...

msg.recycle();
```

the variable `msg` holds a reference named `target` to a corresponding `Handler`. When a Message is proceessed by `Looper`, `msg` is dispatched to the `Handler` (`target` reference), after that, msg is recycled.

[Message.recycle()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Message.java#Message.recycle%28%29) method calls [Message.clearForRecycle()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Message.java#Message.clearForRecycle%28%29) method, in that, we see:

```
...

target = null;

...
```

`target` is set to `null`, that means, `Message` doesn't holds the reference to `Handler`. Non-static `Handler` will be GCed, and both `Activity` and `View`s will be GCed.

So my question is, why there might a memory leak occurs?